# fail2ban missed lines in my filter

Tags: fail2ban

I am completely new to using fail2ban.  Right now I am getting a missed line error but I cannot figure out why.  I have the following two files:

// /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-custom.conf

```
[Definition]

#badagents = 360Spider|ZmEu|Auto Spider 1.0|zgrab/[0-9]*\.[0-9a-zA-Z]*|Wget\(.*\)|MauiBot.*|AspiegelBot.*|SemrushBot.*|PHP/.*

badagents =

failregex = ^.+?:\d+ <HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD) /+dns-query.*$

ignoreregex =
```

// /var/log/apache2/access.log

```
72.139.194.229 - - [17/Nov/2023:01:08:57 +0000] "GET /dns-query HTTP/1.1" 302 4942 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

I then ran the command `fail2ban-regex /var/log/apache2/access.log /etc/fail2ban/filter.d/apache-custom.conf`, and it gave the message:

```
Running tests
=============

Use   failregex filter file : apache-custom, basedir: /etc/fail2ban
Use         log file : access.log
Use         encoding : UTF-8


Results
=======

Failregex: 0 total

Ignoreregex: 0 total

Date template hits:
|- [# of hits] date format
|  [1] Day(?P<_sep>[-/])MON(?P=_sep)ExYear[ :]?24hour:Minute:Second(?:\.Microseconds)?(?: Zone offset)?
`-

Lines: 1 lines, 0 ignored, 0 matched, 1 missed
[processed in 0.02 sec]

|- Missed line(s):
|  72.139.194.229 - - [17/Nov/2023:01:08:57 +0000] "GET /dns-query HTTP/1.1" 302 4942 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 10; K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/119.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

What did I do wrong in my filter? I was expecting my regex to catch this one line in my access.log

Comment: The problem is with your regular expression for catching `/dns-query`

Comment: Try `failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST|HEAD) \/dns-query.*$`

Comment: atually yes your solution worked, thanks!